# Moving a div without pushing another div out of the way

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble figuring out how to get div 6 to take up all the white space next divs's 4, 5, and 7, without moving div 7 out of the way. Appreciate any help. Whenever I move div 6 or make it larger div 7 gets moved down and I do not want that.

Code below in snippet

```css
#test1 {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
}

#test2 {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
}

#test3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 25%;
  clear: both;
}

#test4 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20%;
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}

#test5 {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#test6 {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}

#test7 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  height: 45%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1"> test 1 </div>
<div id="test2"> test 2 </div>
<div id="test3"> test 3 </div>
<div id="test4"> test 4 </div>
<div id="test5"> test 5 </div>
<div id="test6"> test 6 </div>
<div id="test7"> test 7 </div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear ...

Comment: Are you asking how to get 6 to expand 100% "on top of" or "below" s 4 and 5?

Comment: can you share a screenshot of what you looking for..?

Answer (score 2):

You can try flexbox. Use `flex:1` to the div 6 to take the remaining white space.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#test1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%;
}

#test2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 85%;
}

#test3 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

#test4 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 10%;
}

#test5 {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 20%;
}

#test6 {
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1;
}

#test7 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="test1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test2">test 2</div>
  <div id="test3">test 3</div>
  <div id="test4">test 4</div>
  <div id="test5">test 5</div>
  <div id="test6">test 6</div>
  <div id="test7">test 7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a container as a `flexbox` and allow `test6` to grow automatically.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#test1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%;
}

#test2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 85%;
}

#test3 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

#test4 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 10%;
}

#test5 {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 20%;
}

#test6 {
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1;
}

#test7 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="test1"> test 1 </div>
  <div id="test2"> test 2 </div>
  <div id="test3"> test 3 </div>
  <div id="test4"> test 4 </div>
  <div id="test5"> test 5 </div>
  <div id="test6"> test 6 </div>
  <div id="test7"> test 7 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers. Unfortunately none of them worked for what I am trying to do. I am trying to get div 6 to be on the right side of the page with divs 4, 5, and 7 to it's left. Div 7 should be directly under divs 4 and 5. Divs 4 and  5 are right next to one another and have the same combined width as div 7. Div 6 should take up all the remaining space without pushing div 7 out of the way. So it should be 2 divs on top of 1 with another directly to the right. Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Take div test 7 inside 6 it will resolve it. here is the code will look like

```css
#test1 {
background-color: red;
float: left;
width: 15%;

}

#test2 {
background-color: green;
float: left;
width: 85%;

}

#test3 {
background-color: blue;
height: 25%;
clear: both;
}

#test4 {
background-color: orange;
height: 20%;
width: 10%;
float: left;
}

 #test5 {
background-color: grey;
height: 20%;
width: 20%;
float: left;
}

#test6 {
background-color: purple;
height: 30%;
width: 100%;

}

#test7 {
background-color: yellow;
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <div id="test1"> test 1 </div>
 <div id="test2"> test 2 </div>
 <div id="test3"> test 3 </div>
 <div id="test4"> test 4 </div>
 <div id="test5"> test 5 </div>
 <div id="test6"> test 6 
    <div id="test7"> test 7 </div>
 </div>
</html
```